# Bulk Binds over simple inserts in oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, bulkinsert, dblink

I have two databases A and B.
B have some tables that are to be copied to A without any manipulation on the data.

Each table having millions of records.

Which one will give better performance.

option 1:
1.create a dblink in A to B
2.Then create a procedure in A that bulk collects the data from each table in B
3.And then perform bulk binds to tables in A

option 2:
1.create a dblink in A to B
2.Simply to do insert into tables...select * from B_tables@dblink

Please give the reasons behind.

I think option 1 is better.(dont have any logic, but i feel simple inserts are always poor than bulk binds)

Comment: The opposite is true: see this link: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1583402705463, someone asks what is the fastest way ... and the answer is `The fastest way is:   insert into t select * from t2;`

Comment: Thanks for the link kordirko.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use intuition for these issues. They're very simple to test.

However, the general rule is that if you can do something in pure SQL, then do it that way. It's going to be the fastest method because there is no context switch between SQL and PL/SQL. PL/SQL can only change data via SQL anyway, so even if PL/SQL is infinitely fast it cannot be faster than using pure SQL.

Comment: i have to use a procedure to present it to the user. So a procedure with multiple insert into t select * from t2@dblink would be fine. Thanks David Aldridge

Comment: A single insert ought to be better.

Comment: I have to insert data from one table to another table in another database having same name. And there are lot of tables that are  to be mapped in this way. How this could be done using single insert. Is there any way? pls share your thoughts